# iPhone/iPod app that shows text, plays sound and videos

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create an app that shows text, plays sound (mp3 files) and videos (maybe like mp4) on the iPhone/iPod. Sort of like an ebook, but with sound and video players when you click on a play button (plus it should have controls like pause, stop, etc.).

Do you have any suggestions or tips on how I can do this?

I have found individual tutorials on players and all, but not to combine them together or where to start (like what view to use, etc). :(

For example, when opening the app, it shows you something like this:

Yu-Gi-Oh! (遊戯王 Yūgiō?, lit. "Game King" or "King of Games") is a Japanese manga created by Kazuki Takahashi. It has produced a franchise that includes multiple anime shows, a trading card game and numerous video games. Most of the incarnations of the franchise involve the fictional trading card game called Duel Monsters (originally known as Magic & Wizards), where each player uses cards to "duel" each other in a mock battle of fantasy "monsters". The Yu-Gi-Oh! Trading Card Game is the real world counterpart to this fictional game on which it is loosely based.

[video here] 
[play | pause | stop]

Yu-Gi-Oh! tells the tale of Yugi, a shorter-than-average high school student who was given the fragmented pieces of an ancient Egyptian artifact, the Millennium Puzzle, by his grandfather. Upon reassembling the Puzzle, he is possessed by another personality who is later revealed to be the spirit of a 3,000-year-old Pharaoh (5,000-years-old in the English anime) called Atem, with no memory of his own time. As the story goes on, the two of them (together with Yugi's friends), try to find the secret of the Pharaoh's lost memories and his name, with the Duel Monsters card game being an ever prevalent backdrop or plot device.

[audio here]
[play | pause | stop]

Something like that.

Thank you for your help!

~kazuo

Comment: You don't have to "find" a tutorial to be able to do that. You have to try to integrate them all together. Just try and if you have specific problems then ask the question here. Not the whole thing.

Comment: do you have a suggestion on what view to use, etc? That would be very welcome, as I do not know where to start. :(

Comment: Thank you, I will do my best to do that.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go with showing text on iPhone, through pdf,webview or may be textview.Then start working over playing media with AVFoundation ,AudioToolbox frameworks
Then go with playing video with MPMediaPlayer framework.
I have suggested some frameworks which will be used.
Now you can start searching for the implementation and can use that in your app.
Thats the idea...
Now you need to program for that,we are not going to do that for you.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, I will program it myself, I am just asking for suggestions on how to do it.:) thank you for your suggestions.:) It is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome and appreciated....you can find the sample codes as well which will really help you ...like cookbook sample code and so on...just go through those